# How to return result after switchMap operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got service with nested http call. After first request I want to make another with previous result and return all data after completion. I need to pass data with result["Expert"], which is an array with objects {User_key: key1}. So first step in switchMap is to use map operator and to make JSON and then pass it http request.

service.ts

```
getAreaByKey(key: string): Observable<Area> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.API_URL}/v0/areas/${key}`).pipe(
    map(result => {
      return {
        key: result["Key"],
        name: result["Description"],       
        experts: result["Experts"]
      };
  }),
  switchMap(res => {
    res.experts.map(el => {
      let json_data = JSON.stringify(el["User_Key"]);
      this.expertService.getExpertsByKeys(json_data);
    });
  })
}
```

The problem is that I tried to return data after switchMap, but it shows error. Also I can't see second request in dev tools.

Comment: First of all, you have to return an Observable to `switchMap` so the projection function has to have `return`. Then I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do. It looks like you don't need to use `switchMap` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like `combineLatest`? You have multiple input observables, but are interested in the result of all of them (i.e. an array of experts in your case).

Try something like this:

```
switchMap(res => {
    return combineLatest(res.experts.map(el => {
      let json_data = JSON.stringify(el["User_Key"]);
      return this.expertService.getExpertsByKeys(json_data);
    }));
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

SwithMap needs to get an observable in return. You can make use of forkJoin to combine all the elements of result and produce another observable which switchMap can subscribe to internally.

```
getAreaByKey(key: string): Observable < Area > {
  return this.http.get < any[] > (`${this.API_URL}/v0/areas/${key}`)
    .pipe(
        map(result => {
            return {
                key: result["Key"],
                name: result["Description"],
                experts: result["Experts"]
            };
        }),
         switchMap(res => forkJoin([
           ...res.experts.map(el => this.expertService.getExpertsByKeys(JSON.stringify(el["User_Key"])))])
     )
    );
}
```